# Prompting user to save Excel file name based on cell value (using VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to create a macro that will open the Save As window with a file name defaulted in the prompt based on a cell value.

This code works in the initial file I used, however when I copy/paste it into different directories it doesn't show up.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim SvName As String

SvName = Sheets(1).Cells(6, 5).Value

MsgBox ("File should be saved as: " & SvName & ".xlsm")
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show SvName

End Sub
```

The odd thing is even when the code doesn't work (it opens a blank Save As dialogue without the file name inputted), the MsgBox still displays the correct value for SvName.

Why is it not working consistently?

Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the `.Value`

Comment: Try using `Thisworkbook.Path & "\" & svName` instead of just `SvName`  after `.Show`